# Why should compilation fail for this code?

Tags: java

Another SCJP question. I think the output is K=7, but the book's answer is "compilation fails". I just don't see anything wrong with the code.

```
1. class RevQOne{
2.   public static void main(String [] args) {
3.     boolean i = true;
4.     boolean j = false;
5.     short k = 10;
6.    if((k == 10) && (j = true))k--;
7.    if((i = false) || ( k == 9)) 
8.        k--;
9.        k--;
10.     System.out.println("k=" + k);
11.   }
12. }
```

PS: Both the silly = signs in lines 6 and 7, and the if with missing braces in 7, are intentional. The question is meant to test my knowledge of how those things act when misused, I suppose.

Comment: Did you try to compile it yourself?  (Hint, look at your boolean logic comparing "j" and "true")

Comment: Asker is not comparing them, j is being assigned to true, which returns true

Comment: All those numbers on the side (`1.`, `2.`, etc.) will totally confuse the compiler!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, compiled it. Output is indeed k=7. Anita: 1, book: 0. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Not uncommon at all for these SCJP books to give incorrect answers. Do check the latest errata at the book's site, if any. This (and other errors) might have been acknowledged already.

Answer (score 1):

You're completely right.  It does compile (previous answer was wrong), despite the sketchy assignment as value, and that is the output.

Comment: Assignment as value is legal for *any* type.  You just need the overall condition of the `if` to be a `boolean`.

Comment: @dan, you're right.  I was trying to say that you can only use a boolean assignment as value *directly* as the condition, e.g. `if(a = true)`, but I phrased it poorly, and the code isn't actually doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks fine to me.  Is it in a correctly named file?

Comment: It doesn't need to have a particular name, since the class isn't public.